# If using Ruby with Net/HTTP, how to monitor its traffic using Fiddler on Windows or another tool on Mac / Linux?

Tags: ruby, http, monitoring

I usually use Fiddler to monitor HTTP request and response, but if it is a Ruby script using `Net/HTTP`, all the request and response won't show up in Fiddler.

Is there a way to see all the request and response, and if Fiddler can't do it, can any other tool on Mac or Linux show it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this instance, I would use Firefox (Firebug) or Chrome (built in developer tools) to do this

(update: a working answer in the comment)

Comment: as long as it's coming through the browser then yes. Do you mean you are running a stand alone Ruby script from the command line?

Comment: I am using a Ruby script to fetch from www.somewhereonnet.com... it is not a local server

Comment: Ah... In that case Fiddler can not do it. Fiddler needs to 'bind' on to a browser in order to record requests. Try this I think it is what you need - http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1850/show-live-http-requests-being-made-on-os-x

Answer (score 8):

You want to use the Net::Http::Proxy library in your Ruby script.

Where you have

```
Net::Http.start(uri.host, uri.port)
```

you want

```
Net::HTTP::Proxy('127.0.0.1', '8888').start(uri.host, uri.port)
```

. . . assuming Fiddler is running on port 8888, as it does out of the box.

Comment: And what if I want to use it with HTTPS connections from Ruby?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/)?

And maybe you can get Fiddler to work by using a proxy - sending net/http to 127.0.0.1:8888 for instance.

Comment: WireShark is a great tool for this, and is what I'd grab.