# Getting the last HTTPS Request in Ruby rest-client (like __getLastRequest in php SoapClient)

Tags: ruby, rest, https, rest-client

I'm using the ruby rest-client to send requests to a web service.  My requests are working, but I'd like to see the actual request that was sent to the service.

I can't do this with Wireshark or tcpdump because I'm using https and don't have access to the servers private key.

In php, when I've used the SoapClient in the past, I've been able to use the __getLastRequest function to see what xml is sent (http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php).

Does anyone know the best way for me to see the actual packets sent to the server?

Many thanks,
D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Net::HTTP instead of rest-client, you can use `http.set_debug_output $stderr` to see the contents of the request and response:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'
uri = URI('https://myserverip/myuri')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.set_debug_output $stderr
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request.basic_auth 'username', 'password'
response = http.request(request)
@data = response.body
puts response.body
```

In addition, using Net::HTTP, I can also get it to [use a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140132/if-using-ruby-with-net-http-how-to-monitor-its-traffic-using-fiddler-on-windows) by using something like `http = Net::HTTP::Proxy('127.0.0.1','8888').new(uri.host, uri.port)`.

You can also do the same with rest-client by using `RestClient.proxy = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/"` just before your `RestClient.get(url)` etc..

This way I can send the traffic via a tool like [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/) on Windows and then see all the detail I need.

It's just a shame I can't find an equivalent to Fiddler for the Mac since that's where I want to write the code.

It Looks like I'll either have to rewrite my code to use HTTP::Net instead of rest-client, or switch to Windows full time ;), unless anyone has any other thoughts.

Comment: It seems you can get fiddler for mac under the [Fiddler for Mono](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono) project.  I've managed to get http traffic ok, but haven't got https working yet...

Answer (score 2):

You can set the environment variable `RESTCLIENT_LOG` to `stdout`, `stderr` or a file name:

*test.rb:*

```
require 'rest-client'
RestClient.get "http://www.google.de"
```

Call:

```
RESTCLIENT_LOG=stderr ruby test.rb
```

Output:

```
RestClient.get "http://www.google.de", "Accept"=>"*/*; q=0.5, application/xml", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate"
# => 200 OK | text/html 10941 bytes
```

Comment: Thankyou.  That's useful, but unfortunately doesn't give me the full request output, just the headers?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately. The library just doesn't support it. But however, you *can* decrypt that traffic using wireshark. Check this for example http://packetpushers.net/using-wireshark-to-decode-ssltls-packets/

Comment: I'm stuck at the second requirement "The private key used to encrypt the data must be available on the system running Wireshark." -- I don't think I can get the private key?

Comment: It's *your* private key not the servers one. (I'm not sure where it is stored at the moment.. But think, if *your* browser is able, then every other program should be too.. isn't it?)

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get Wireshark to decode it.  I have found that when using Net::HTTP instead of rest-client I can use `http.set_debug_output $stderr` which seems to provide me with the full detail of the request.